# Run a piece of code only once in background whenever user login

Tags: android

Ia trying to get user locations whenever its login the application.I made a class and its working perfect seperately but when I embed it in my main project it didnt submit the location values in database.I want that whenever user login that class run for only once and submits its coordinates in database.

Here Is the code of my location class :
I want that when user login this class class run for once only all I want is to get user location when its loged in.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class getposition extends AppCompatActivity {
    String URL_LOGIN = "api"
    Button btn;
TextView tv1,tv2;
LocationManager locationManager;
static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
String lg, lt , chk;
String lat_long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_getposition);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.send);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.lang);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.lat);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        chk = getLocation();
       loadlocation();

        if(chk != "false"){

            String foo = chk;
            String[] split = foo.split("_");

            lt = split[0];
            lg = split[1];

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chk,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    private void loadlocation() {
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getposition.this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                tv1.setText(response);
                tv2.setText(response);
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                tv1.setText("Something went wrong///");
                error.printStackTrace();
                requestQueue.stop();
            }
        })
        {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user_id","12" );
                params.put("user_lat", lt);
                params.put("user_lng", lg);
                return params;
            }
        };


        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getposition.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }

    public String getLocation() {



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);


        else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latt = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();

                lat_long = latt + "_" + lng;

                tv1.setText("Latitude: " + latt);
                tv2.setText("Longitude: " + lng);

            } else {

                lat_long = "false";

                tv1.setText("Unable to find correct location.");
                tv2.setText("Unable to find correct location. ");
            }
        }

        return lat_long;
    }
}
```

This is my login class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.VolleySingleton;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.MainActivity;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.R;
import com.vshine.neuron.riseshine.getregistered;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button login_button;
    ImageButton GetRegistered;
    EditText userName_edt, password_edt;
    String user_name, password;
    Context mctx;
    String json_response;
    String URL_LOGIN = "api"
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferenceFiles";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mctx = this;
        initBasic();
        initLogin();
    }

    private void initBasic() {
        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        GetRegistered = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.register);
        userName_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    private void initLogin() {
        GetRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(login.this,getregistered.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user_name = userName_edt.getText().toString();
                password = password_edt.getText().toString();
                if (user_name.trim().equals("") || password.trim().equals("")) {
                    ShowToastMessage("Please enter the credentials properly");
                }
                else {
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {
                                        //converting response to json object
                                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                                        //if no error in response
//                                        json_response = j_obj.getString("message");
                                        if (response!= null) {
//                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            json_response = obj.getString("message");
//                                            ShowToastMessage(json_response);
                                            //getting the user from the response
                                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("response");

                                            //creating a new user object

                                            String u_id = String.valueOf(userJson.getInt("id"));
//                                            ShowToastMessage(u_id);
                                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                            editor.putString("User_id", u_id);
                                            editor.commit();
                                            finish();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("user_name", user_name);
                            params.put("password", password);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    VolleySingleton.getInstance(login.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private void ShowToastMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear of exactly what is the issue that you're encountering at the moment.

Comment: when user login the app call the broadcast receiver .and in onRecieve method get the lat,lng of user and save into database

Comment: @AhsanMalik Iam new to jaa can you please elaborate more

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html ,,,  see this tutorial

Comment: @AhsanMalik what if I want to run the loadlocation method of getlocation class in login class under onclick of login button.What will be the procedure

Comment: Iam trying by writting this code in onclick of login button
getposition inst = new getposition();
   inst.loadlocation();
but its crashing the app.

Comment: it is not a good practice by calling a function from one class , any way make object of getlocation class and in onCreate of login class initialize it by doing object = new getlocation(this);